# htaccess redirect all pages/variables/path except

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

move from subdomain

http://randy.savage.com

to

http://www.randy.com

i would like that http://randy.savage.com/path/path/path
will be transported to the new domain also.

Except

http://randy.savage.com/you/are/pretty

http://randy.savage.com/maybe/dance

etc.

those should stay like they are

how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^randy\.savage\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(you/are/pretty|maybe/dance) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.randy.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: hi again. thx. this broke all images but otherwise would work. not yet usable. thanks for any improvement.

Comment: thanks for your efforts. life will reward you for altruistic behaviour.